# Cloning Jquery Time Entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery Time Entry by Keith Wood. My problem is how to clone form it. I know how to clone a form but if I clone the form time entry, it won't. Please help me.

Comment: A sample of your current JS code would be helpful to answerers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code to clone the time form...

```
$('#defaultEntry').timeEntry().change(function() {
    console.log($(this).clone());
});
```

Here i use clone method of jquery to clone the time entry text box in time entry change event.

Hope this will help you...